# How to use a Google Earth recorded tour video for animation work?

Tags: video, google-earth

I have trial version of [Google Earth Pro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Earth#Google_Earth_Pro). I have seen that there is a record tour option.
I tried to record one tour after enabling 3D view. Now I want to save and use the video, say in [Maya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodesk_Maya) or [3ds Max](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodesk_3ds_Max), to use in an animation project. How can I do that?

When I tried to save, `.kmz` and `.kml` files got generated.

Answer (score 0):

Google Earth supports the following formats.

- Windows Media Video (WMV)
- Audio Video Interleave (AVI)
- QuickTime (Mac only)

See [Making Movies with Google Earth](http://earth.google.com/userguide/v5/ug_movies.html).

Follow these steps to record your movie:

1. From the Tools menu, select Movie Maker. The Movie Maker dialog box appears.
2. From the Supported Compression Formats selector, choose the desired compression format for your movie.
   If you want to have a movie format other than WMV (Windows Media Video) or .mov (QuickTime), check the Advanced checkbox and choose the format. If you choose another movie format, only standard AVI compression is available. Note that AVI formats are not compressed and therefore will result in large files.
3. Select *High Quality* or *Standard Quality* as the movie quality. See Movie Quality Levels for details.
4. Choose the *Frames Per Second* (FPS) you desire for your movie. The highest FPS setting, 60, offers the smoothest movie viewing experience, but at the cost of a large file size. Typically, a setting of 30 works fairly well for movies that you want to provide over the Internet.
5. Choose the resolution for your movie. You'll want to choose a resolution that is appropriate for your final movie display. From 320x240 to 1920x1080 (HD).
6. Specify a name for your movie. Click on the *Browse* button and navigate to a location on your computer where you want to save the movie file when you are finished recording. Type in a name for the file in the file dialog box and click on the *OK* button.